# jquery .change trigger not working

Tags: jquery

I have a gallery with a main image that changes when the thumbnails are hover on. And then I am using a zoom plugin for the main image div. The zoom plugin is only getting the first image on document load. What is wrong with my code here to have the image change when the main image div has a new image in it?

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.hikashop_main_image_div').zoom({ 
        on:'grab',
        magnify: 2,  
    });
});

jQuery('.hikashop_main_image_div').change(function(){
    jQuery('.hikashop_main_image_div').zoom({ 
        on:'grab',
        magnify: 2,  
    });    
});
```

Comment: Link to zoom plugin docs?

Comment: http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/

Comment: Pretty sure .change() http://api.jquery.com/change/ event only works on certain form elements.

Comment: The 'change' event is limited to <input>, <textarea> and <select> elements.

Comment: okim a noob, what would my alternative be?

Comment: Can you post your markup for the "gallery"? This seems like really easy functionality to build out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If im not mistaken this should do it.

`jQuery('.hikashop_main_image_div').hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).zoom({ 
        on:'grab',
        magnify: 2,

    });

});`

Comment: and i removed the document.ready function as it was giving me double images